# Using FALSE is necessary in DATE_FORMAT sql in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I tried to use

```
$this->db->select("orders.*, DATE_FORMAT(orders.created, '%M %e, %Y - %l:%i %p') AS OrderDate, users.id AS UserID, users.username AS UserName");
```

but this was generating error... but when i used False as 2nd parameter like this

```
$this->db->select("orders.*, DATE_FORMAT(orders.created, '%M %e, %Y - %l:%i %p') AS OrderDate, users.id AS UserID, users.username AS UserName", FALSE);
```

the error was gone....
Why is it necessary to use `FALSE` as 2nd parameter in `DATE_FORMAT` function in model in CodeIgniter?

Comment: `$this->db->select()` accepts an optional second parameter. If you set it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table names with backticks. This is useful if you need a compound select statement. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, because it can't parse functions (with more than one parameter) and/or subqueries.